# Slide from right to left on screen using MonkeyRunner in android device

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

I am doing some automation using monkey runner, so for that i want auto slide from left to right on  the screen using monkey runner?

So any one know how to do this?

Vertical drag i know because we have drag() API.

Thanks in adv....

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
void drag ( tuple start, tuple end, float duration, integer steps)
```

you can specify any point on the screen as `start` and `end`.